# install elementary os freya grub-pc

Tags: release-freya, system-installation, boot, grub

I tried installing elementary os freya on my dell laptop, at the end of installation, I get "grub-pc failed to install on target..."

As a remark, I installed ubuntu gnome 14.10 without getting any error.

you help will be much appreciated.

thanks.

Comment: try installing with internet connection =)

Comment: How it is a duplicate of ^ question ?

Comment: not duplicate, when finishing the installation without boot loader, the computer boots directly to windows, without any grub!